# Querying the closest date to another date in seperate columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wanting to join table 1 to table 2 and want to query 'com_fur_date' to be the one closest (in the future) to the action_taken_date to get analysis on how the action taken effects the com_fur reasons

Im stuck on how to do this and other queries ive seen dont seem to resolve the issues

[Table examples]

[image: 1]

Heres my code to join the tables together

```
select
   a.ACTION_TAKEN_DATE,
   a.RULE_DESCRIPTION,
   a.SERVICE_ID,
   b.COM_FUR_DATE,
   b.FUR_REASON_CODE b.Circuit_id,
   CASE WHEN COM_FUR_DATE is NULL THEN 'No further' ELSE 'Further' END as Further_Status
from table 1 a
LEFT JOIN table 2 b ON a.SERVICE_ID = b.CIRCUIT_ID;*
```

I just need to know how I can relate the **action taken date** to the closest **com fur date** (in the future) so I can get cause and effect as there is numerous SERVICE_ID/CIRCUIT_ID (same ref) with different dates in both tables

Hope this makes some sort of sense, lol

Answer (score 1):

just to demonstrate the part you need:

```
select * from table1 a
lateral ( 
select * from table2 b
where b.COM_FUR_DATE  >= a.action_taken_date
order by b.COM_FUR_DATE asc 
fetch first row only
) r
```